# Display Page Title of cms page in 1column.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, template

I am working on Magento 1.9. By using `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>`, it is Displaying the content Heading, content and Breadcrumbs, but I want to know how to Display the CMS Page Title and the Content Heading in a specific tag From `1comumn.phtml`.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
<?php $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle(); ?>
<?php $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setDescription(); ?>
```

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67126/change-page-title-and-meta-description-in-phtml-file